# Why aren't non-Jews commonly called "Ivrim"?

Tags: gentiles

This article claims that one opinion is that the word "Ivri" is related to "Ever", one of Noah's descendants.

The Bible uses the term "Ivri" in many places. Avram was called an "Ivri" ([Breishit (Gen.) 14:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=186&hilite=)). Considering that Ever had many non-Jewish (i.e. non-Abraham) desendants, or for that matter, descendants of Ishma'el or Esav, etc. why aren't these descendants also called "Ivrim" or "Hebrews" based on this definition?

Comment: Babe Ruth is called the Sultan of Swat because he swat so many home runs. Other players though have hit as many too. Why aren't they all called "Sultans of Swat" based on this definition?

Comment: Yona Hanavi " וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֲלֵיהֶ֖ם עִבְרִ֣י אָנֹ֑כִי"

Comment: what about מעבר לנהר

Comment: @kouty, "Ivri" is used in numerous places in Tanac"h. In the Torah, Avra(ha)m and Yosef are called Ivrim. I know about Yonah. (Moshe, interestingly, was referred as being a "mitzri" - Egyptian.). At any rate, I mentioned the 1st occurrence of the term in Tanac"h.

Comment: `This article claims...` Which article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the other etymological possibilities for the term "Ivri" which would preclude all but Avraham's descendants, the Stone Chumash (Gen 14:13, page 63) reads

> Only Abraham's descendants are called "Ivrim" for they alone spoke Hebrew, Eber's language. Eber's other descendants spoke Aramaic, and are called Arameans. (Radak)